# web3 smart contract calls to slow (arrays / lists)

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura

I call contract like this :

```
  static async getInitialProps(res) {


    const users = await UsersContract.methods.getUsers().call();
    const totalusers = await UsersContract.methods.getTotalUsers().call();
    var i;
    const emails = [];
    const usersETHaddr = [];



    for (i = 0; i < totalusers; i++) {

     emails.push(await UsersContract.methods.getUserEmail(i).call());
     usersETHaddr.push(await UsersContract.methods.getUserETH(i).call());

    }


    return { emails,usersETH};

  }
```

When i have 10-15 users inside the array it loads ok 
But when i have 20-30 users it takes around 3 minutes to load

I use infura not geth

So why does it load slower when i add more users to the array ?

Comment: You have a `for` loop on the number of users, and you're asking why it takes longer when you add more users? What exactly are you expecting, that it would run faster???

Comment: i need the for loop

Comment: What has that got to do with what I wrote?

Comment: it's a for loop outside the contract , not inside the contract ,making calls per total users , do to fact no solution to call all users with one call ...

Comment: inside for loop call 1 gets user 1 ,call 2 gets user 2 ,you can not do call 1 call user 1 + user 2 + user n

Comment: If speed really matters, you could deploy a new contract with custom getters that returns everything you are looking for.